# Time VS Random Number

Tags: security, encryption, random, hash, cryptography

I have been wondering, is there any merits to using current time instead of generating a random number in terms of security.
For instance, before hashing, using Time as the salt instead of generating a random number as the salt?

Comment: Depends on where you want to use the output. For critical applications, the time is a predictable quantity. Even if you hash the current time, it becomes predictable once again after someone figures out that you are hashing it. The easiest attacks start with predictable values so it is best to avoid anything that is easy to predict.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: That totally depends on your threat model and use case in the protocol design, but since you're talking about salts (and therefore password hashes), you want a secure random value provided by a CSPRNG (e.g. libsodium's `randombytes_buf()`).